# Issue with Magento currency switcher

Tags: php, magento, currency

My currency switcher works fine up till I add a product in my cart. After adding a product in my cart if I change the currency the website crashes and gives me a fatal error of memory:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in /home/ubuntu/domains/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1328
```

Answer (score 3):

This error can occure when you have observer for events `sales_quote_collect_totals_before` or `sales_quote_collect_totals_after` and in methods for this observers you try to get quote object e.g by `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()`. Solution for this is to get quote like this:

> public function observerMethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
>   { $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote(); }